# handle escape sequence char in DB2

Tags: db2

I want to search a column and get values where value containts \ .

I tried `select * from "Values" where "ValueName" like '\'`. But returns no value.

Also tried `like "\"` and `like'\''%'`  etc. But no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the DB2 Documentation on the [LIKE predicate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000751.html), in particular the parts about escape expressions.

What you want is

```
select * from Values where ValueName like '\\%' escape '\'
```

To give an example of usage:

```
create table backslash_escape_test
(
backslash_escape_test_column varchar(20)
);

insert into backslash_escape_test(backslash_escape_test_column) 
values ('foo\');
insert into backslash_escape_test(backslash_escape_test_column) 
values ('no slashes here');
insert into backslash_escape_test(backslash_escape_test_column) 
values ('foo\bar');
insert into backslash_escape_test(backslash_escape_test_column)
values ('\bar');

select count(*) from backslash_escape_test where 
backslash_escape_test_column like '%\\%' escape '\';
```

returns 3 (all 3 rows with \ in them).

```
select count(*) from backslash_escape_test where 
backslash_escape_test_column like '\\%' escape '\';
```

returns 1 (the \bar row).

Comment: Doesnt work. I tried '%\\%' and 'Prefix\\%'. Both returned with no values.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the "ESCAPE" part of it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Values where ValueName like '%\\%'
```

values is a not so good name because it may be confused with the values keyword

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape it.  You just need wildcards around it like this:

```
select count(*)
  from escape_test
  where test_column like '%\%'
```

---

But, suppose you really do need to escape the slash.  Here's a simpler, more straightforward answer:

The escape-expression allows you to specify whatever character for escaping that you wish.  So why use a character that you're looking for, thus requiring you to escape it?  Use any other character instead.  I'll use a plus sign as an example, but it could be a backslash, pound-sign,  question-mark, anything other than a character you are looking for or one of the wildcard characters (% or _).

```
select count(*) 
  from escape_test
  where test_column like '%\%' escape '+';
```

Now you don't have to add anything into your like-pattern.

To hold myself to the same standard of proof that @Michael demonstrated --

```
create table escape_test
( test_column varchar(20) );

insert into escape_test 
         (test_column) 
  values ('foo\'),
         ('no slashes here'),
         ('foo\bar'),
         ('\bar');

select 'test1' trial, count(*) result
  from escape_test
  where test_column like '%\%' 
UNION
select 'test2', count(*)
  from escape_test
  where test_column like '%\\%' escape '\'
UNION
select 'test3', count(*)
  from escape_test
  where test_column like '%\%' escape '+'
;
```

Which returns the same number of rows for each method:

```
TRIAL RESULT
----- ------
test1   3
test2   3
test3   3
```